# Strange MySQLi OO error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'll try asking this again but without typing mistakes.... I'm connecting using MySQLi and using intentionally bad connection variables to trigger an error.

Working as expected:

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","x","x","x");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Couldn't establish database connection blah blah";
  }
```

This should work exactly the same, but it showing a "Can't fetch MySQLi" warning:

```
  $conn = new mysqli("localhost","x","x","x");
  if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Couldn't establish database connection blah blah";
  }
```

Both methods are fine when the connection details are good, although that isn't the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This didn't work properly in some older versions of PHP.

If you are using a PHP version before 5.2.9, the `$conn->connect_error` (and I think also `$conn->connect_errno`) method did not function properly, and you had to use `mysqli_connect_errno()` instead.

The [MySQLi constructor docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) talk about this.

> The mysqli->connect_error property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the mysqli_connect_error() function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.

```
// May need to use the procedural method, even in OO context...
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","x","x","x");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Doh, 5.2.6!  I'll update myself, but just checked the target host, and it's also 5.2.6 and I can't change that, so I guess I'll write it non OO :)

Comment: @Codecraft To be clear, you can use MySQLi fully OO except for this one error check on connection. I just changed the `mysqli_connect()` to `new mysqli()` above.  copy/paste error.

Comment: Thanks, btw.  My faith has been restored, 2nd attempt at asking this question after it was hijacked and downvoted by people who didn't stop to actually read it properly before...